# Настройка ftp (или VPN) для общего доступа через интрнет

Tags: windows, сеть, ftp, vpn, fedora

Есть две машины: моя (Linux Fedora) и другая (Windows), соединены через интернет, т.е. прямого подключения по сети нет.

Нужно создать директорию на одном из компьютеров для общего доступа. Можно на моем линуксе. Читал, что для этого используют ФТП, но конкретного примера найти не удалось. Насколько понимаю, мне нужно будет настроить ФТП сервер и указать какой-нибудь адрес по которому будет доступ к данной директории.

Также встречал, что можно использовать и VPN. Но здесь я вообще не представляю как это делается.

Мне без разницы каким способом пойти. Машины две и пока больше не предвидится. Они расположены на расстоянии 70 км, так что рекомендации "проще бросить сетевой шнур" — бессмыслены.

Comment: Вам нужен выделенный ip адрес, проброшенный на роутерах 21 порт и любая инструкция по настройке ftp сервера

Comment: А вот выделенного ip как раз и нет.

Comment: Выделенный адрес ip это накладно, vpn тоже не бесплатно, пользуйся `https://cloud.mail.ru`

Comment: @AlexGlebe только в Украине он недоступен.

Comment: Очевидно, что при отсутствии выделенного ресурса (например белого IP, имени и т.д.), для решения задачи необходимо найти дополнительный ресурс. Т.е. нужно найти сервис, который выделит (судя по условиям задачи) **бесплатный** ресурс.Попробуйте воспользоваться триал-предложениями VPN-сервисов. Естественно, они имеют ограничения: поскорости; по объему; по количеству соединений и т.д. Но обеспечить соединение двух хостов Интернета могут.

Comment: Ну тогда уж проще "подпилить" приложение для box.com для синхронизайци под Линукс. Под виндой десктопный вариант синхронизирует нормально, а для линукса нет.